# How can I check a group of numbers are consecutive in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If i was to have a table with an integer column containing *n* number of rows and wanted to check if they were consecutive, how could I do this?

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE 
(
    IntegerValue INT,
    Processed BIT
)
```

I have a solution that works for 3 rows but this is infelxable, if the requirements change then so would the query (ignoring the fact that my sum wouldnt work in this case).

```
@SumOfValues = (@FirstValue * @NumOfValues) + @NumOfValues
```

Comment: What means for you "numbers are consecutive" ? You assume, somehow, that your rows are ordered ?

Comment: The numbers are inserted into the temp table in numerical order 1, 2, 3, 5, 66, 899, ...

Comment: So what happens if the source values are 1,2,3, 100,101,200 ... ? Do you want to `group` consecutive rows (`IntegerValue`) ?

Comment: No, if the values were 1,2,3,100,101,200 these numbers are not consecutive and should fail the test.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT IntegerValue) /*Or COUNT(*) dependant on how
                                            duplicates should be treated */ 
                =  1 + MAX(IntegerValue) - MIN(IntegerValue) THEN 'Y'
         ELSE 'N'
       END
FROM   @Temp
```

If you want to know where the gaps are you can use

```
;WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY IntegerValue) - IntegerValue AS Grp
FROM @Temp
)
SELECT MIN(IntegerValue) AS RangeStart, 
       MAX(IntegerValue) AS RangeEnd
FROM T
GROUP BY Grp
ORDER BY MIN(IntegerValue)
```

Comment: I really like this answer. It works when there are duplicates or not, as long there are no gaps. But I think for the strict non-duplicate case to work, the query should be: `(COUNT(DISTINCT IntegerValue)=1+MAX-MIN) AND (COUNT(*)=1+MAX-MIN)`

Comment: Oh, I see the light now. If `IntegerValue` is unique, checking only the `COUNT(*)=...` is enough.

Comment: @ypercube - Yep agreed. Although for the non duplicate case I guess there will be a good chance that there will be a unique index on `IntegerValue` anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE #T(ID INT)
DECLARE @i INT
SET @I = 1
WHILE(@I <= LEN('12235588966'))
BEGIN
  IF(SUBSTRING('12235588966',@i,1) = SUBSTRING('12235588966',@i-1,1))
  BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #T SELECT SUBSTRING('12235588966',@i,1)
  END
  SET @i = @I +1
END

SELECT * FROM #T
```