# Get sibling rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, common-table-expression

I need to get the two sibling rows of a specified row in a query.

```
SELECT pkUserId, name
FROM tblUsers
ORDER BY CreateDate
```

Gives result:

```
10 User1
18 User3
25 User4
79 User8
12 User2
```

I want a query that gives me `user3` and `user8` if I supply userId 25

```
10 User1
18 User3 --> Output
25 User4 <-- Input
79 User8 --> Output
12 User2
```

If think it should be possible to get this with a single query (without Union) using `ROW_NUMBER()`, but Im not sure how the create it.

Comment: What indicates that User3 and User8 are siblings of User4?

Comment: I guess I don't understand. You have them ordered by CreateDate, and User 4 is right in the middle, yet you want User3 who is above, and User8 who is below. Do you always want to show who was created directly before and after the user? So if i queried on 79 it would return User4 and User2? I normally read sibling as just the immediately following one, not the previous one.

Comment: Yes @Blake that's is exactly how I want it.

Comment: You need LAG and LEAD Oracle's equivalent function, try looking here : http://www.rafael-salas.com/2008/05/t-sql-lead-and-lag-functions.html

Comment: @Scorpi0 The link provide LAG and LEAD emulation in SQL server using CTE, ROW_NUMBER which is what the answers here are about

Comment: I know, I just comment to add some vocabulary to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: I added four remarks for the second solution.

Two solutions:

(1) The first solution is based on MAX, MIN functions:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestData
(
     PKUserID INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
    ,CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_TestData_CreateDate_PKUserID
ON  dbo.TestData(CreateDate, PKUserID);

INSERT  dbo.TestData
SELECT 10,'User1','2011-01-01T00:00:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT 18,'User3','2011-01-01T00:10:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT 25,'User4','2011-01-01T00:20:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT 79,'User8','2011-01-01T00:30:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT 12,'User2','2011-01-01T00:40:00';

DECLARE @UserID INT;
SELECT  @UserID = 25;

DECLARE @UserCreateDate DATETIME;
SELECT  @UserCreateDate = a.CreateDate
FROM    dbo.TestData a
WHERE   a.PKUserID = @UserID;

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT  TOP 1 a.PKUserID
    FROM    dbo.TestData a
    WHERE   a.CreateDate < @UserCreateDate
    ORDER BY a.CreateDate DESC, a.PKUserID DESC
) a
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM
(
    SELECT  TOP 1 a.PKUserID
    FROM    dbo.TestData a
    WHERE   @UserCreateDate < a.CreateDate
    ORDER BY a.CreateDate ASC, a.PKUserID ASC
) b

DROP TABLE dbo.TestData;
```

Results (**10 logical reads**):

```
PKUserID
-----------
18
79
```

(2) The second solution is inspired, somehow, from the [quirky update](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/) method but not implies any `UPDATE`, it's just a simple `SELECT`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestData
(
     PKUserID INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
    ,CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_TestData_CreateDate_PKUserID
ON  dbo.TestData(CreateDate, PKUserID);

INSERT  dbo.TestData
SELECT 10,'User1','2011-01-01T00:00:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT 18,'User3','2011-01-01T00:10:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT 25,'User4','2011-01-01T00:20:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT 79,'User8','2011-01-01T00:30:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT 12,'User2','2011-01-01T00:40:00';

DECLARE @UserID INT;
SELECT  @UserID = 25;

DECLARE @PreviousID INT
        ,@NextID INT
        ,@IsFound BIT
        ,@CountAfter INT; 

SELECT   @IsFound = 0
        ,@CountAfter = 0;

SELECT   @IsFound = CASE WHEN a.PKUserID = @UserID THEN 1 ELSE @IsFound END
        ,@PreviousID = CASE WHEN @IsFound = 0 THEN a.PKUserID ELSE @PreviousID END
        ,@CountAfter = CASE WHEN @IsFound = 1 THEN @CountAfter + 1 ELSE 0 END
        ,@NextID = CASE WHEN @CountAfter = 2 THEN a.PKUserID ELSE @NextID END
FROM    dbo.TestData a WITH(INDEX=IX_TestData_CreateDate_PKUserID)
GROUP BY a.CreateDate, a.PKUserID
ORDER BY a.CreateDate ASC, a.PKUserID ASC
OPTION  (MAXDOP 1);

SELECT @UserID UserID, @IsFound IsFound, @PreviousID [Prev], @NextID [Next]

DROP TABLE dbo.TestData;
```

Results (**2 logical reads**):

```
UserID      IsFound Prev        Next
----------- ------- ----------- -----------
25          1       18          79
```

**To prevent getting wrong results:**

1. I used `MAXDOP 1` query hint to prevent "parallelism".
2. I created an unique index that includes all necessary fields starting with fields used in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.
3. I forced `INDEX=IX_TestData_CreateDate_PKUserID` index.

<strike>Or the simplest solution is to force an execution plan using `OPTION (USE PLAN N'<?xml...><ShowPlanXML...')`.</strike>

Comment: `MAX/MIN/TOP` is definitely the way to go if you're not trying to be clever (although the last solution is interesting). A window query (rownum) will force two full index scans for a problem that's easily solved with seeks.

Comment: @Bogdan You second solution is very interesting. But how is forcing the index preventing getting wrong results? Is not the `Order By` sufficient?

Comment: @Magnus: [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) is `FROM ... SELECT ... ORDER BY ...`. So, SQL Server is not forced to execute `ORDER BY` before `SELECT ...`. I rephrase: at logical level, I don't have any warranty that `ORDER BY ....` will be executed before 'SELECT ...'. And this is the "key point" for this solution: it assume that `SELECT ...` will read ordered rows and computations from `SELECT` clause will be done after `ORDER BY`.

Comment: `WITH(INDEX=...)` + `ORDER BY ... ASC, ... ASC` try to force `SQL Server` to read sorted rows before computations. But I can't say that this is 100% safe. The safest method is to freeze a good plan (`OPTION USE N'<xml...>')`. Also, please read the last comment of Martin Smith from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608370/how-can-i-check-a-group-of-numbers-are-consecutive-in-t-sql/7608990#7608990).

Comment: @Bogdan - BTW you can't force the position of a compute scalar in a plan. [Not all elements of the XML-formatted query plan are forced with the USE PLAN hint. Elements that compute scalar expressions are ignored](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186954.aspx) In fact before when I tried using the plan hint against a query which previously had a good plan (compute scalar to the left of the sort) just to ensure that it kept this plan it ended up working against me and the compute scalar ended up on the right which is why I discovered this.

Comment: Indeed. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186954.aspx) I have found this text:`The Assert, Bitmap, ComputeScalar, and PrintDataFlow operators are ignored by USE PLAN.` But, a simple solution can alleviate the problem: `GROUP BY same fields as in order by`. From logical point of view, `GROUP BY` is executed before `SELECT ...`. The overhead introduced by `GROUP BY` can be small with a propper unique index (ex. `IX_TestData_CreateDate_PKUserID`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CreateDate) [rn], pkUserId, name
    FROM tblUsers
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE c
WHERE c.rn =
(
    SELECT c2.rn
    FROM CTE c2
    WHERE c2.pkUserId = 25
) - 1
OR
c.rn =
(
    SELECT c3.rn
    FROM CTE c3
    WHERE c3.pkUserId = 25
) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is almost as doing a union solution. Is it possible to do it without repeating the query? My real query is very expensive to run so I want to avoid having to run in twice.

Comment: @Magnus: The query cost has *nothing* to do with the amount of code repetition. That is not how databases work. In fact, any solution using `ROW_NUMBER` is going to be highly inefficient for such a simple problem.

Comment: You wrong about that, the query cost on your answer compared to @Adrian is 72% vs 28%. And that is because the CTE is used multiple times inside the query. But thanks for the example using row_number, it pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the whole solution, including the virtual declarations, so that anyone can verify the solution:

```
declare @tblUsers table (pkUserId int, name varchar(20), createdate datetime)

insert into @tblUsers values 
(10, 'User1','2011-01-01'),
(18, 'User3','2011-01-02'),
(25, 'User4','2011-01-03'),
(79, 'User8','2011-01-04'),
(12, 'User2','2011-01-05')

;with sel as(
SELECT pkUserId, name, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by createdate) rn
FROM @tblUsers
) 
select sel.pkUserId, sel.name 
from sel, 
(
select rn from sel where pkUserId = 25
) item
where sel.rn in (item.rn -1, item.rn+1)
```

Comment: Ignoring syntax details: the CTE and the join are not necessary:
`select * from (select pkuserid, name, lag(pkuserid) over w, lead(pkuserid) over w from tblusers window w as (order by createdate)) x where pkuserid = 25 or lag = 25 or lead = 25`

Answer (score 0):

Use subqueries in the following order:

1. Query for the input row
2. Query for the foreign key
3. Query for the siblings

Here is an example:

[Search Text in Other Answers to Questions I've Answered](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/181740/search-text-in-other-answers-to-questions-ive-answered)