# SQL Server - Find records with identical substrings

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I inherited a table that has a column containing hand-entered award numbers.  It has been used for many years by many people.  The award numbers in general look like this:

```
R01AR012345-01
R01AR012345-02
R01AR012345-03
```

Award numbers get assigned each year.  Because so many different people have had their hands in this in the past, there isn't a lot of consistency in how these are entered.  For instance, an award sequence may appear like this:

```
R01AR012345-01
1 RO1AR012345-02
12345-03
12345-05A1
1234506
```

The rule I've been given to find is to return any record in which 5 consecutive integers from that column match with another record.

I know how to match a given string, but am at a loss when the 5 consecutive integers are unknown.

Here's a sample table to make what I'm looking for more clear:

```
+----------------------+
|  table: AWARD        |
+-----+----------------+
| ID  | AWARD_NO       |
+-----+----------------+
| 12  | R01AR015123-01 |
+-----+----------------+
| 13  | R01AR015124-01 |
+-----+----------------+
| 14  | 15123-02A1     |
+-----+----------------+
| 15  | 1 Ro1XY1512303 |
+-----+----------------+
| 16  | R01XX099232-01 |
+-----+----------------+
```

In the above table, the following IDs would be returned:  12,13,14,15

The five consecutive integers that match are:

```
12,13: 01512
12,14: 15123
12,15: 15123
```

In our specific case, ID 13 is a false positive... but we're willing to deal with those on a case-by-case basis.

Here's the desired return set for the above table:

```
+-----+-----+----------------+----------------+
| ID1 | ID2 | AWARD_NO_1     | AWARD_NO_2     |
+-----+-----+----------------+----------------+
| 12  | 13  | R01AR015123-01 | R01AR015124-01 |
+-----+-----+----------------+----------------+
| 12  | 14  | R01AR015123-01 | 15123-02A1     |
+-----+-----+----------------+----------------+
| 12  | 15  | R01AR015123-01 | 1 Ro1XY1512303 |
+-----+-----+----------------+----------------+
```

Now... I'm OK with false positives (like 12 matching 13) and duplicates (because if 12 matches 14, then 14 also matches 12).  We're looking through something like 18,000 rows.  Optimization isn't really necessary in this situation, because it's only needed to be run one time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem by adding the code that isn't working.

Comment: Have a look at [How can I check a group of numbers are consecutive in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608370/how-can-i-check-a-group-of-numbers-are-consecutive-in-t-sql)

Comment: @Kermit: It seems the 4 example OP given has 1-5 on all the cases. Which need to consider as duplicate

Comment: @huMptyduMpty - the OP's question seems quite different than that. I think he's looking for rows containing identical strings that are 5 digits long. But the 5 digits could be anywhere in the column values. The 5 digits just have to be contiguous.

Comment: The numbers could be anything... we're just looking for 5 contiguous integers that match any other 5 contiguous integers.  There is not always a dash... sometimes they neglect to enter it.

Comment: @Lawson: can you please give an example of the expected output? Your example values appear to all match each other. In order to get appropriate answers, we need to see what you expect in terms of columns as well as rows for both matching and non-matching conditions.

Comment: I'll add a sample table to the question.

Comment: @Lawson, in your example table, you don't have any award numbers that are purely digits like you show towards the top (e.g. `1234506`). I ask because the query could be made smarter to remove some false positives if that situation never happened.

Comment: I actually got something that works... I'm posting the solution now.

Comment: @Lawson, I see you have a solution that mostly works, but if you are up for using RegEx you can do something even better that might rule out all false positives and include the case where the first 5 don't match.

Comment: I no longer need the answer to get the data I was asked for (because they're OK with errors), but I'm always up for learning if you want to help out.

Comment: Am almost done with my test...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should handle removing duplicates and most false-positives:

```
DECLARE @SPONSOR TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, AWARD_NO VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @SPONSOR VALUES (12, 'R01AR015123-01')
INSERT INTO @SPONSOR VALUES (13, 'R01AR015124-01')
INSERT INTO @SPONSOR VALUES (14, '15123-02A1')
INSERT INTO @SPONSOR VALUES (15, '1 Ro1XY1512303')
INSERT INTO @SPONSOR VALUES (16, 'R01XX099232-01')

;WITH nums AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS [Num]
    FROM sys.objects
),
cte AS
(
    SELECT sp.ID,
           sp.AWARD_NO,
           SUBSTRING(sp.AWARD_NO, nums.Num, 5) AS [TestCode],
           SUBSTRING(sp.AWARD_NO, nums.Num + 5, 1) AS [FalsePositiveTest]
    FROM   @SPONSOR sp
    CROSS JOIN nums
    WHERE nums.Num < LEN(sp.AWARD_NO)
    AND SUBSTRING(sp.AWARD_NO, nums.Num, 5) LIKE '%[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
--  AND SUBSTRING(sp.AWARD_NO, nums.Num, 5) LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
)
SELECT sp1.ID AS [ID1],
       sp2.ID AS [ID2],
       sp1.AWARD_NO AS [AWARD_NO1],
       sp2.AWARD_NO AS [AWARD_NO2],
       sp1.TestCode
FROM cte sp1
CROSS JOIN @SPONSOR sp2
WHERE sp2.AWARD_NO LIKE '%' + sp1.TestCode + '%'
AND sp1.ID < sp2.ID
--AND 1 = CASE
--           WHEN (
--                   sp1.FalsePositiveTest LIKE '[0-9]'
--               AND sp2.AWARD_NO NOT LIKE
--                        '%' + sp1.TestCode + sp1.FalsePositiveTest + '%'
--                ) THEN 0
--           ELSE 1
--         END
```

**Output:**

```
ID1   ID2   AWARD_NO1        AWARD_NO2        TestCode
12    14    R01AR015123-01   15123-02A1       15123
12    15    R01AR015123-01   1 Ro1XY1512303   15123
14    15    15123-02A1       1 Ro1XY1512303   15123
```

If IDs 14 and 15 should *not* match, we might be able to correct for that as well.

**EDIT:**

Based on the comment from @Serpiton I commented out the creation and usage of the `[FalsePositiveTest]` field since changing the initial character range in the LIKE clause on the SUBSTRING to be `[1-9]` accomplished the same goal and slightly more efficiently. However, this change assumes that no valid Award # will start with a 0 and I am not sure that this is a valid assumption. Hence, I left the original code in place but just commented out.

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I was asking for.  It's going to take several minutes of runtime to get the full results, but should work well for smaller-sized result sets.

Comment: @Lawson: Glad this works. So was (14, 15) a valid match or false-positive?

Comment: @Lawson: Also, if the performance isn't great, you can create a temp table and do an INSERT into it from the CTEs. Then the file SELECT can use the temp table instead of `cte` as `sp1`.

Comment: @srutzky Instead of a cross join why don't you self join cte? Like "FROM cte sp1 inner join cte sp2 ON sp1.testcode = sp2.testcode and sp1.id < sp2.id", also for the false positive maybe the LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' can be changed to LIKE '%[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' so that 0 cannot be the first char of the testcode.

Comment: @Serpiton: thanks for the suggestions! I did test it out and doing the self-join was actually much worse for logical reads. However, the idea to get rid of FalsePositiveTest in favor of the initial character range being changed to [1-9] did reduce logical reads, not to mention removed a bunch of code. I updated my answer to reflect that and put in a note about not being sure if it is a valid assumption that the first digit can't be a 0 (just in case).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the LIKE command in your where clause and use a pattern to look for the 5 numbers. See this post [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx):

There are probably better ways of representing this but the below example looks for 5 digits from 0-9 next to each other in the data anywhere in your column value. This could perform quite slowly however...

```
Select *
from blah
Where column LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a sql server function to extract the 5 numbers and then use the function in your query.

Perhaps something like:

```
 select GetAwardNumber(AwardNumberField) as AwardNumber
 from Awards
 group by GetAwardNumber(AwardNumberField)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will not post the code, but an idea on how to do it.

First of all you need to make a table valued function that will return all number sequences from a string bigger then 5 characters. (there are examples on SO)
So for each entry your function will return a list of numbers.

After that the query will simplify like:

```
;with res as (
  select 
    id,                             -- hopefully there is an id on your table
    pattern                         -- pattern is from the list of patterns the udtf returns
  from myTable
  cross apply udtf_custom(myString) -- myString is the string you need to split
)
select 
  pattern
from res
group by pattern
having count(distinct id)>1
```

I have to note that this is for example purposes, there should be some coding and testing involved, but this should be the story with it.

Good luck, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with:

```
SELECT a1.ID as AWARD_ID_1, a2.ID as AWARD_ID_2, a1.AWARD_NO as Sponsor_Award_1, a2.AWARD_NO as Sponsor_Award_2
FROM AWARD a1
LEFT OUTER JOIN AWARD a2
    ON SUBSTRING(a1.AWARD_NO,PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',a1.AWARD_NO + '1'),5) = SUBSTRING(a2.AWARD_NO,PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',a2.AWARD_NO + '1'),5)
WHERE
    a1.AWARD_NO <> '' AND a2.AWARD_NO <> ''
    AND a1.ID <> a2.ID
    AND a1.AWARD_NO LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' AND a2.AWARD_NO LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

There's a possibility that the first substring of five characters might not match (when they should generate a match), but it's close enough for us.  :-)

Comment: Try using `AND a1.ID < a2.ID` to see if you can eliminate duplicates.

Comment: THANK YOU!  That cut my results down from ~17,000 to ~8,000